# JavaScript creates and saves a file to local file system

Tags: javascript, html, file, filewriter

I'm building a website and plan to save some data to the local file system (Windows). The data will be returned from server-side PHP code via AJAX method. Once the JavaScript receives the echoed data, the data will be written to a newly created local file. I'm wondering how to implement that function. An example found online (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) uses the following API:

```
function onInitFs(fs) {

fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {

// Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

  fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
    console.log('Write completed.');
  };

  fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
  };

  // Create a new Blob and write it to log.txt.
  var blob = new Blob(['Lorem Ipsum'], {type: 'text/plain'});

  fileWriter.write(blob);

  }, errorHandler);

 }, errorHandler);

}

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

While this paragraph of JavaScript codes is free from error, the newly created file "log.txt" is nowhere to find. Even after I rename it in the code to an unique name, I still cannot find the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested it, google doesn't create a file named log.txt (but the file will be accessible via the File-API by using this name).

For me (WinXP) the file is located in

```
 %LOCALAPPDATA%/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/FileSystem/
```

You'll find there some folders named by numbers, inside these folders may be 2 folders named `t` and `p` .
You have ro search within the `t`-folder(because you have used `window.TEMPORARY`)

Inside the t-folder is one more folder named by numbers, which contains files named by numbers. These files are the stored files.

For me it's e.g.

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/FileSystem/000/t/00/00000000
```

Comment: I couldn't find the newly created file in those folders. I give up.

Answer (score 0):

To view files created in Chrome, you can make use of a file system explorer plugin:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-filesystem-explorer/nhnjmpbdkieehidddbaeajffijockaea

Although I've used the plugin, I'm in no way affiliated with its development so you'll have to make up your own mind if you trust it enough to install it locally. Good luck!